# I have made a frame with panel in Java (Eclipse), the application does not close on pressing the cross button

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, panel, frame

This is my first question, so please correct me if any errors exist.

This is the code, I tried making a frame with a panel but the application does not quit on pressing the close button.

When I tried to set the default close operation to quit then it showed me an error.

So, please help me out.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class FramewithPanel {

    private Frame f;
    private Panel p;

    public FramewithPanel(String title){
        f = new Frame(title);
        p = new Panel();
    }

    public void LaunchFrame() {
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setBackground(Color.blue);
        f.setLayout(null);

        p.setSize(100,100);
        p.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FramewithPanel guiWindow = 
            new FramewithPanel("Frame with Panel");

        guiWindow.LaunchFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your question you are speaking of an error. It might be useful  to share the error/stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you've mentioned that you are insistent on using `Frame` rather than the alternative `JFrame`, the simplest solution is to add a `WindowListener` like so:

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Et voila!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use a `JFrame` instead of a `Frame`, as a `Frame` does not have a default close operation. Instead it won't close at all but only generate a `WindowEvent` of type `WINDOW_CLOSING`.

So you'd either do

```
private JFrame f;

// and in the constructor
f = new JFrame(title);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

or

```
f = new Frame(title);
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        f.dispose();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I already know that and I wanted to use just a Frame. I believe that Frame was used earlier also when the JFrame was not there.

Comment: @Sarthak You're perfectly right. Although I generally don't recommend it, you can of course use a `Frame` aswell. The `WindowListener` does exactly the same thing like the `defaultCloseOperation`. Just that it's invoked at a slightly different time, but this won't matter in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate!